# Google Analytics not tracking Google Ads and UTMs clicks correctly

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-ads-api, utm

I've identified a discrepancy between Google Ads clicks and Analytics sessions in Paid Search (about twice more clicks than sessions). So I contacted Google Ads support and after a long conversation, they send me an email saying that my website structure uses redirections and it's making it lose parameters, and that I had to contact a developer to solve that problem because they don't give assistance on it. What exactly they told me to tell the developer was that:

> Loss of parameters by redirection
>
> The website trendotrends.com is not holding navigation parameters
>   because of the structure in which it was developed.
>
> To verify this redirection, simply replicate the following steps: I
>   accessed the link
>   https://trendotrends.com/products/running-shoes?variant=15320930779194
>   After full site loading, I added the & gclid = Tester123 parameter to
>   the URL (in the browser, so the final URL was
>   https://trendotrends.com/products/running-shoes?variant=15320930779194&gclid=Tester123)
>   and hit Enter To understand if there is a redirect, the normal
>   behavior would be for the URL to remain the same (with & gclid =
>   Tester123 at the end), but in this case, the parameter disappears (and
>   hence the assignment) This link was just an example, which can be
>   verified in several other products of the site.

They also said I can't use manual tagging (UTMs) instead of automatic tagging in Google Ads because those redirections are also going to spoil the UTMs.

I don't use any redirections in my website and I have also tested with UTMs and there's also a discrepancy in google analytics data for that.

But before I contact a developer and invest on this fix, I would like to know if anyone had experienced that? If Googles answer fits this problem? And even if is there a way to fix it without being an expert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here isn't really that there's a redirect (301), but a state change. There is javascript on the page that essentially rewrites the URL before the GA code can parse it.

Are you able to change to a different theme and test if this happens with that theme?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help! I can do that, but should I do the same test (add &gclid= ester123 at the end of the URL)? And what kind of javascript code should I look at? If I move the GA code to the very top of the page it would be a solution?

Comment: I inspected the "network" tab in chrome when loading your site, and it didn't show a redirect, the requested page was actually the one with all the parameters.You should to use https://get.google.com/tagassistant/ to record and generate a report on your visits to see if the campaign information is being registered. I also tried stepping through the JS on your site, if you put breakpoints in the JS you can step through until you see the URL change, this will help you narrow down what's changing the URL.Though whoever designed your shopify site might help you to solve this faster.

Comment: I think I got the problem. The theme automatically adds the product variant to the URL. For exemple, if I try to go to:

https://trendotrends.com/collections/trends/products/inception-totem-kit

It automatically adds (redirects) ?variant... at the end:

https://trendotrends.com/collections/trends/products/inception-totem-kit?variant=13945330073658

And I guess somehow its causing the removal of the tags on the URL. When I test on other pages, that doesnt have a variant (non product pages), the tags are kept. Exemple:

https://trendotrends.com/pages/contact?gclid=Tester123

Comment: Yes, if you can modify the code that adds the variant to also keep the parameters that came with the request, then you should be good.

Comment: I am in contact with the theme developer and shopify to see how can I remove this variant redirection. Thanks for all the help!